# Display Related Value in Table Visual With a Hierarchy

Tags: powerbi, dax

### Data

#### Main

| Group | Subgroup | Value | Composite Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | A - 1 |
| A | 2 | 2 | A - 2 |
| B | 1 | 3 | B - 1 |
| C | 1 | 4 | C - 1 |
| C | 1 | 5 | C - 1 |
| C | 2 | 6 | C - 2 |
| C | 2 | 7 | C - 2 |

#### Targets

| Group | Subgroup | Target | Composite Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 | A - 1 |
| A | 2 | 11 | A - 2 |
| B | 1 | 12 | B - 1 |
| C | 1 | 13 | C - 1 |
| C | 2 | 14 | C - 2 |

### Setup

I have 2 datasets like the ones given above. Table `main` stores, well, my main data and table `targets` defines tragets for each combination of `Group` and `Subgroup`. I want to bring this 2 tables in a relation. Thus, I created columns in each table which paste the 2 key columns (`Group` and `Subgroup` together (`Composite Key`) and defined an `1:n` relationship between these 2 tables.

Furthermore, I defined a hierarchy on `Group > Subgroup` on the `main` table (lets call it `group hierarchy`).

[image: Table Relations]

[image: Hierarchy Definition]

### Goal

I want to show a matrix visual which uses `group hierarchy` in the rows (effectively allowing to fold / unfold the groups), some measure as values. So far so good. Now I want to add the target from table `targets` to the visual and here is where I am struggling, because if I simply add `Targets[Target]` to the visual it only shows the overall average of the targets and not the average of the specific group. Hence, I guess I need to define a meausre myself which does some `RELATEDTABLE` magic to pull the correct target, but I am totally at loss of how to do that. Any ideas?

[image: Wrong Targets in Matrix Visual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I need to define the hierarchy on `Targets` as well and use this hierarchy in the visual:

[image: Hierarchy on Targets]

Then the numbers were calculated properly:

[image: Numbers are calculated properly]